# jQuery not selector with class match

Tags: jquery-selectors

How can I use jQuery to select all div elements that do not contain a class starting with the string 'upper' and do not contain a class starting with the string 'lower'. I tried the following couple of examples with no success:

```
$('div:not([class^=upper])').filter(':not([class^=lower])')
```

and

```
$('div').not('[class^=upper])').not('[class^=lower])')
```

Please advise...

Comment: It seems to work for me just fine http://jsfiddle.net/D3BCJ/

Comment: For me it returns all div's, and does not filter out those based on the not condition. Are you sure it isn't doing the same for you?

Comment: Turns out all the options work if there are not multiple classes. Because the upper and lower classes were not first in a space separated list the not operation was failing until I changed it to [class*=upper] and [class*=upper]

Sorry for the boondoggle, feel free to down vote this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit verbose, but it should do the trick -

```
$('div').filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("class").substring(0,5).toLowerCase() != 'upper' && $(this).attr("class").substring(0,5).toLowerCase() != 'lower'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [:not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('div:not([class^=upper,class^=lower])');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote the string values in the comparison.  In either of your examples above, replace `lower` with `"lower"`.  Do the same for upper.

Comment: The nested quotes did not make any difference. Although most scripts use nested quotes, the examples in the book "jQuery in Action" do not, which is why I left them off originally.